# Unable to properly animate the frame of a subview within a parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift4.1

I am trying to animate the frame change of a subview within a view. Within the animation block I am setting the size of the subview to half its original width and height. However, when I run the code, the subview unexpectedly started with a larger size and shrunk to its original size instead of becoming half its original size. I am using the code below:

My custom view:

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    var testSubview: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        testSubview = UIView(frame: .zero)
        testSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        addSubview(testSubview)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        testSubview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    func testAnimate() {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { [unowned self] in

            self.testSubview.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)

            }, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

My view controller:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let testView = TestView()
        view.addSubview(testView)

        testView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        testView.center = view.center

        testView.layoutIfNeeded()

        testView.testAnimate()
    }

}
```

Am I doing something wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your view gets laid out two times, you can check that by printing a debug message inside layoutSubviews().

I would suggest something like this, setting a size variable and use that in both layoutSubviews() and testAnimate():

```
class TestView: UIView {
    var testSubview: UIView!
    var mySize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        testSubview = UIView(frame: .zero)
        testSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        addSubview(testSubview)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        testSubview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mySize.width, height: mySize.height)
    }

    func testAnimate() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: [], animations: { [unowned self] in
            self.mySize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
            self.testSubview.bounds.size = self.mySize
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have a number of distinct subviews, do I have to keep track of all the different sizes using separate instance variables? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Reformulating my whole answer because there are many things I feel should be changed here.

first of all the difference between setting the bounds of a view and it's frame.

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200) // This will set the position and size this view will take relative to it's future parents view
view.bounds = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100) // This will set position and size of it's own content (i.e. it's background) relative to it's own view
```

Then comes your testView class variables. Unless you are certain that a variable won't be nil don't use `UIView!` as the typing, you would end up missing some initialisers and thus your class would not work consistently.

Consider init methods as default values for your variables and you can simply alter them afterwards.

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    var testSubview: UIView

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // Initialise your variables before calling super
        testSubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        testSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Once super is called you can start using class methods or variable such as addSubview or backgroundColor
        backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        addSubview(testSubview)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        testSubview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        testSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        addSubview(testSubview)
    }

}
```

now finally to the animation part

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    var testSubview: UIView

    func testAnimation() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
            self.testSubview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5) // Simply make the view half its size over 3 seconds
        }) { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
                self.testSubview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1) // Upon completion, resize the view back to it's original size
            })
        }
    }
}
```

or if you really want to use CGRect to do animation on it's position

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {

    var testSubview: UIView

    func testAnimation() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
            self.testSubview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50) // use frame not bounds to resize and reposition the frame
        }) { (_) in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
                self.testSubview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

you can test the effect of changing the bounds attribute as such

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var testView: TestView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        testView = TestView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
        testView.bounds = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        testView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(testView)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        testView.testAnimation()
    }


}
```

simply play around with `clipsToBounds`, `testView.bounds`, `testView.subView.frame` and `testView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x:y:width:height)` to see all of this